# Add new item in context menu using powershell gives an error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a context menu but once its created i get an error message stating
This file does not have a program associated to it.
i am using this script . I am trying to create a powershell shortcut on folders.

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Test-Path HKCR:\Directory\shell\Powershell
New-Item -Path HKCR:\Directory\shell -Name Powershell
Set-Item -Path HKCR:\Directory\shell\Powershell -Value "Open Powershell Here" 
New-Item -Path HKCR:\Directory\shell\Powershell\key -Value    
"C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -
LiteralPath '%L'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change last line:

```
 New-Item -Path HKCR:\Directory\shell\Powershell\key -Value "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command ""Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'"""
```

If not work add a third '"' `"""Set-location...`